# How do I check for child theme files first using include, before going to parent theme?

Tags: child-theme

I'm creating a WordPress child theme based on an existing parent theme, and I'd like to have any same-named file I put in my child theme directory take priority over the file in the parent theme directory. I thought this was how parent/child theming was set up in WP but I have hit a bump.

According to the [WordPress codex on Child Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Template_Files), it says:

> **Template Files** 
>  
>   If you want to change more than just the stylesheet,
>   your child theme can override any file in the parent theme: simply
>   include a file of the same name in the child theme directory, and it
>   will override the equivalent file in the parent theme directory when
>   your site loads.

In one of my files (header.php), there is an include that looks like this:

```
include get_parent_theme_file_path("folder/file.php")
```

Even though I have a duplicate-named-but-modified version of that file.php in my child theme, it still uses the version in my parent theme. According to the same codex, their recommendation for targeting a child theme file specifically is to use get_stylesheet_directory(), so it would look like this:

```
include (get_stylesheet_directory()."/folder/file.php");
```

I understand that the purpose of a function called "get_parent_theme_file_path()" is to ignore the parent/child relationship and just get the parent theme version, so without replacing that with a function that explicitly gets a file in my child theme (ie. get_stylesheet_directory), **is there a way I can have some sort of universal get_path() function that checks for child first, if it doesn't exist, get parent version?**

By the way, I read [this Q&A on "get_parent_theme_file_path vs. get_template_directory"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257597/get-parent-theme-file-path-vs-get-template-directory/257613), but their solution was to use parent_theme_file filters, but that isn't dynamic, and would require me to write a filter function for every child file I want it to use.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially what [`locate_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/locate_template/) does.

> Searches in the STYLESHEETPATH (child) before TEMPLATEPATH (parent) and `wp-includes/theme-compat` so that themes which inherit from a parent theme can just overload one file.

Comment: Bingo, bango, bongo! Thank you @Milo.

I wonder why this isn't mentioned on the Child Theme codex?

Answer (score 5):

There is a function for this since 4.7: [`get_theme_file_path()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_file_path/)

> Searches in the stylesheet directory before the template directory so themes which inherit from a parent theme can just override one file.

So if you do this:

```
include get_theme_file_path( 'folder/file.php' );
```

`folder/file.php` will be loaded from the child theme, if it exists, otherwise the parent theme.

This doesn't work for `get_stylesheet_directory()`, because the actual file path is not passed to `get_stylesheet_directory()`, so it has no way of knowing what file to look for.

The equivalent function for URLs is [`get_theme_file_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_file_uri/). This will get the URL for a file if it exists in the child theme, otherwise it will get it for the file in the parent theme.

Each function has a matching version that only searches the parent theme:

```
get_parent_theme_file_path();
get_parent_theme_file_uri();
```

For templates, you should use [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/). This lets you include PHP files that can be replaced by child themes, with some extra features, like an optional suffix to the name.

PS: The Codex is somewhat outdated. Unless a specific article has yet to be ported over, the developer documentation you should use is at https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. This works, and gives me more control, but for the purpose of flexibility, I'm going to use the `locate_template` function. I just read [this](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/09/09/new-functions-hooks-and-behaviour-for-theme-developers-in-wordpress-4-7/#comment-31278) about the differences between the two functions.